# finding link in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

this is a code in my project :

```
<textarea id="url" ></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convert()
{
  var text=document.getElementById("url").value;
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
  var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  document.getElementById("converted_url").innerHTML=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#url").keypress(function( event ) {
      $("#converted_url").html($(this).val());
         if ( event.which == 32 ) {
            convert();
         }
  }).keyup(function(){
     $("#converted_url").html($(this).val());
  }) ;
 });
</script>
<p id="converted_url" ></p>
```

When i type something in textarea and press space if there is a link in text the code will link the url in the `converted_url` .

I wanna know how to show links in textarea only if it's possible.

If not what can i do to type the text and show the link in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display  tags in textarea. So you can use `div contenteditable` instead. Try the following code on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/alexdant91/xfbwtgk9/32/)

Basically the functions replace only the link outside the  tags in html source from div and then replace cursor at the end of text.

Good luck.

Comment: that's good but there is a problem , when i press space two time it goes to new line. how can fix this??

Comment: I've just updated the code, try it now! https://jsfiddle.net/alexdant91/xfbwtgk9/32/

Comment: sorry about that but after typing a url when i press space it goes to new line.

Comment: Where you test it? Jsfiddel or localhost?

Comment: both localhost and jsfiddel